# mysql union wrong columns in result

Tags: mysql, union

I am getting wrong column names when using union.

Here is what i do, i have two very big tables with same structure and different records, so here it is.

```
mysql> select * from e18 where `15` like '%car%' limit 1;
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| id   | 1    | 2  | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9    | 10   | 11   | 12   | 13   | 14   | 15          | 16   | 17   | 18   | 19   | 20   | 21   | 22     | 23   | 24   | 25   | 26   | 27   | 28   | 29   | 30   | 31   | 32   | 33   | 34   | 35   | 36   | 37   | 38        |
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| 2730 | 2730 | 18 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | cars: stuff | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |  5  1  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | yy        |
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
1 row in set

mysql> (select * from e8 where `15` like '%car%') union
(select * from e10 where `15` like '%car%') union
(select * from e18 where `15` like '%car%') limit 1;");
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| id   | 1    | 2  | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    | 8    | 9    | 10   | 11   | 12   | 13   | 14   | 16   | 17          | 18   | 19   | 20   | 21   | 22   | 23   | 24   | 25     | 26   | 27   | 28   | 29   | 30   | 31   | 32   | 33   | 34   | 35   | 36   | 37   | 38   | 15        |
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
| 2730 | 2730 | 18 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | cars: stuff | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |  5  1  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | yy        |
+------+------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----------+
1 row in set
```

Union all and union return same result in this case.

There is only one row with word part "car" in it and it is in table e18.

**For some reason, column names in result that i get from using usion are messed up, looks like i am missing something, any ideas what it is ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'messed up'?

Comment: There's not enough detail to be able to explain the situation.  Use an alternate name, but be careful not that it isn't too abstract

Comment: ok i edited my post, check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Union works by column *position* NOT name. But you have not specified the column position because you did `*` so it's in some order picked by the database, but not picked by you.

The name of the final result set is the name of the columns in the first query in the union.

The fix is easy: Write out the names of all the columns you want, and make sure to keep the order consistent between all three queries.

The columns are NOT sorted by name (so renaming the columns will not help you), the order is some internal order in the database.

Using `*` is considered poor practice: You don't know what you are getting, and if you only need some of the columns then using `*` retrieves more data then necessary, making things slower.

BTW Naming columns like this (by number) is very poor programming practice. How in the world do you keep things straight? Your columns have numbers, your tables have numbers. Are you trying to write obfuscated code? To make sure no one else can ever work on your code? Because if you are, this is one way to do it.

Comment: That is not as easy as it sounds, i got more then 60 columns now and no, i dont try to obfuscate anything x) it's just that those tables are being generated automatically and this data was not supposed to be stored or requested directly.

Comment: @RaslyWalker Even if you are generating the tables automatically you should still give normal names to things. 60 columns? What are you storing? And you also have a lot of NULLS - I strongly suspect the tables are not designed correctly, they should be normalized and split up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the first query your field `15` is in numerical order with the other fields. In the 2nd query, it's showing up at the end.  If you specify the fields you want (yes I know it's a lot of typing), then you won't have this problem.

Secondarily,  given the number of NULLs in your return set and the fact that you're using multiple tables to store the same sort of data, your data probably isn't well normalized. Your database will be much easier to use (as well as faster and more efficient) if you normalize it.

And thirdly, `15` is **not** a reasonable field name -especially not when sibling fields are named for other numbers.

Comment: thanks, do you think i can fix it by renaming columns like c15 c16 c17 ... ?

Comment: @RaslyWalker:  it might work. I do not believe that SQL is required to output columns in a particular order unless that order is defined in the query.  What I wonder, given how generic your column names are, is what you are storing.  Are all the columns holding the same kind of data? ie, are you using the db table more like a spreadsheet or a matrix than a relational table?  If you are, your best bet is to reconsider your table structure. Columns should hold readily classifiable data that should be easy to name with a descriptive name.  When they don't, it's a symptom of possible problems.

Comment: I dont think this will help in anyway but i guess they are more or less relational like table, most of columns hold very similar data, like strings and numbers, but columns are not 100% defined and may be changing, so i cant give them descriptive names. Also im not naming them myself, those tables are created automatically.