# MySQL index optimisation in select using " or " and without

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have one query that i want to be fast, but there is somethings that i dont understand yet.

I do a simply test using 3 queries.

in my table there are columns
`1` and `3` are int's with normal key (each has its own index)
`15` and 35 are string's with fulltext key (each has its own index)

First

```
select `1` from el where ( `15`='Bump' or `35`='Bump' and `3`='1' ) limit 1;
```

Time: 250ms

Second

```
select `1` from el where ( `35`='Bump' and `3`='1' ) limit 1;
```

Time: 0.024ms

Third

```
select `1` from el where ( `15`='Bump' and `3`='1' ) limit 1;
```

Time: 0.007ms

**and my question is: wtf ? also how to fix it ?**

Thanks in advance!

> edit: ok it seems like this is a mysql limitation and cant be realy
>   fixed, so i decided to just run two queries instead of one, i get
>   0.031ms and this is way better then 0.270ms.

Comment: @Ariel give a good answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix it directly, it's a limitation of MySQL that it can only read from one index to do a query, but there is no single index that can handle all three conditions when they are `OR`.

i.e. it has to individually check each one to look for any rows that match, but no single index can be certain to exclude rows, so no index can be used at all.

With `AND` it can pick one, find rows that match, then filter them further (without using an index) to make sure they match the rest of the conditions.

So how to fix? Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT `1` FROM el WHERE `15`='Bump'
UNION
SELECT `1` FROM el WHERE `35`='Bump'
UNION
SELECT `1` FROM el WHERE `3`='1'
```

This runs the checks individually, then combines them.

PS. Yes, MySQL should do this automatically, but it doesn't. You may wish to look into PostreSQL - I'm not certain about it, but I think it can handle this type of query.

Comment: That explains it, still im a bit consern about using UNION, it does sometines messes up columns for me, but that would be another question.

Comment: also i chose MySQL instead of PostreSQL because i though MySQL is faster.

Comment: @RaslyWalker UNION does not mess up column - but you have to make sure all the columns are the same in all the queries. MySQL can be faster than PostgreSQL, but it depends on how you use it and what you use it for, it's not a blanket thing.

Comment: maybe you can help me with my other question about `union` and `columns` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714577/mysql-union-wrong-columns-in-result

Comment: @RaslyWalker OK, I wrote you an answer.